# dense_rank function error and not able to proceed further

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions

I have used below query in Fiddle application for learning purpose but its throwing error:

```
with result as 
(
  select salary, dense_rank() over (order by salary desc) as 'dense_rank'
  from salary
)
select salary from result where result.denserank = 3
```

Error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near '(order by salary desc) as 'DENSE_RANK' from salary' at line 1

What to do further.? Also is Mysql and postgreSql same

Comment: What version of mysql are you using? You can't use dense_rank in mysql 5.x

Comment: Typo in last line: You want `select salary from result where result.DENSE_RANK =3` to match the name you gave that column in your CTE. And change `'DENSE_RANK'` to `DENSE_RANK` without the `'` characters in the third line.

Comment: Single qoutes are for string literals. Use "DENSE_RANK" or remove quotes at all.

Comment: @SalmanA it's gotta be MySQL 8+ or MariaDB 10.2+. It has a CTE.

Comment: @O.Jones it won;t give syntax error in MySQL 8, but a different error of course.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you're using a MySQL version that supports CTEs but does not support Window functions. MySQL 8.0.1 is such version ([8.0.1](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-1.html) introduces CTEs for the first time and [8.0.2](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-2.html) introduces window functions).

You need to use a more recent version of MySQL and (ii) change `where result.denserank = 3` to `where result.dense_rank = 3`.

Comment: Thanks for your help..!
Also is sqlite and postgres are same in query commands.. ? 
Time being am learning in youtube and using online compiler to try my learnings.

https://sqliteonline.com/

Comment: No idea about SQLite but it should work as-is in PostgreSQL